# Fatal error: Call to a member function setArea() on a non-object in /home/hoods/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php

Tags: magento-1.9, fatal-error, supee-6788

Our website theme has been having issues with the `Magento Patch 6788`. The theme developers sent me their patch this morning and I went ahead and copied over the files that they provided for me. Now when I load up the website or the front end I am given these errors:

**Admin Area:**

> `Fatal error: Call to a member function setArea() on a non-object in
>
> /home/hoods/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php
>   on
>
> line 157`

**Front End:**

> Fatal error: Call to a member function setArea() on a non-object in
>   /home/hoods/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php
>   on line 62*

Line 157 would be:

```
$this->getLayout()->setArea($this->_currentArea);
```

Any idea of what would have caused this?

Comment: Did you clear cache and logout and log back in?

Comment: Our Admin area isn't accessible as well. I've tried clearing out the cache manually through a FTP Client but still no avail.

Answer (score 5):

I just had the same and found out by debugging that there was an invalid rewrite for the layout model `Mage_Core_Model_Layout`. In fact, I had an incomplete install of *Inchoo_PHP7* where the `config.xml` file was in place but the class `Inchoo_PHP7_Model_Layout` which was given as a rewrite was not. 
Thus, the solution was to add the full module *Inchoo_PHP7* module (branch 1.9.2.4).